# Still have problems with gridview and update for my database project

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview, sql-update

I want to Update An Number of goals That a Player Scored so if he socred a goal I want to do an update for his number of goals...
I got an Error in my Code And I don't know how to fix it. Can anyone help me to fix it, please ?

My Code:

```
        string connectionStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\SoccerDataBase.mdb";
    using (OleDbConnection sqlCon = new OleDbConnection(connectionStr))
    {
        sqlCon.Open();
        string queryStr = "SELECT Achievement FROM SoccerAchievements WHERE UserID=@AchNums";
        OleDbCommand sqlCmd = new OleDbCommand(queryStr, sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AchNums", (SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("AchNums") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
        OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryStr, sqlCon);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapt.Fill(ds, "SoccerAchievement");
        DataRow row = ds.Tables["SoccerAchievement"].Rows[0];
        int a = int.Parse(row[3].ToString());
        a = a + int.Parse("@AchNums");
        string query = "UPDATE SoccerAchievements SET Achievement= '" + a + "' WHERE UserID= @AchNums";
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

My GridView HTML CODE:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SoccerTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="3" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="קוד שחקן" InsertVisible="False" 
                SortExpression="ID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Team" HeaderText="קבוצות" SortExpression="Team" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Players" HeaderText="שחקנים" 
                SortExpression="Players" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="הישגים">
                <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="AchNums" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button class = "AddButton" ID="AddButton" runat="server" onclick="AddButton_Click" Text="עדכן" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <RowStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#007DBB" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#00547E" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

My Error: There is no row at position 0.
Image:

[image]

## My Data SoccerAchievements

Image:
[image]

Please help me guys :)

Comment: You should pass userid in parameter to command object, where's you are passing achnums which is not userid looking at your code.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this
`OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(queryStr, sqlCon);`
With
`OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapt = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlCmd);`

However you may again face error at your `int.parse` code.please correct that as well.

Comment: Thank you for the help bro, how can i help my int.parse error?

Comment: In the int.parse you need to provide a value "@achNums" is treated as a string. Provide the textboxes value just like you added in the `parameter.add`

Comment: Like that:            int a = int.Parse("@AchNums".ToString());
            a = a + int.Parse("@AchNums");               ???

Comment: No row at 0 means your query didn't produce any results. And you need to use `int.parse((SoccerTable.FooterRow.FindControl("AchNums") as TextBox).Text.Trim());`

Comment: Check in your table if you have records for the userid you are passing

Comment: Also I m fearing you are passing achnum to your where clause whereas you should be passing a userid.